# Global Variables - Python

Tags: python, function, variables, global

I'm having trouble with global variables, yet again. I'll put my code into a small example. I assign a variable named var1, in function1. Now I want to call that variable in function 2 and then print the results of function 2

If I use this code, I get a var1 is not defined.

```
def function1():
    global var1
    var1 = 'Hello'

def function2():
    return var1


print function2()
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: Do you ever call `function1`?

Comment: Define var1 global before starting your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to actually *call `function1()`* first.

The `global` keyword only tells Python that *when you call the function*, any assignment to `var1` should be to a global, not a local name. But that doesn't magically make `var1` appear until you actually execute that assignment. Until you call `function1`, there is no global `var1`.

Python has no declarations; names are either bound or not bound.

Demo:

```
>>> def function1():
...     global var1
...     var1 = 'Hello'
... 
>>> def function2():
...     return var1
... 
>>> function2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in function2
NameError: global name 'var1' is not defined
>>> function1()
>>> function2()
'Hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make `global var1` in `function2()`, you should call `function1`in `function2`. Doing that `var1` became visible and accessible to return in `function2`:

```
 >>>def function2():
 ...    function1()
 ...    return var1
```